# Why is the output of my JavaSript function undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

can anybody please hint me what is wrong in my Javascript function below?
I am finding the maximum multiple between two numbers.
When I write the code which is not inside the function in my testing window it works and it gives me what I need, but if I want to enclose it in my function the output is undefined. I believe that I miss something stupid but I have been solving that for several hours and I can not see it.

```
function maxMultiple(d, b){
  const arr = []; 
  for (let i=b; i<=d; i+=b) { // i = i + b
       arr.push(i)}
  if (d>0 && b>0){
     return arr.pop(); // does not work - undefined
  } else { 
  return d; }
 }

console.log(maxMultiple(7,100));  // Output is undefined

// it works....
/*
let b = 7;
const d = 100;
const arr = [];
for (let i=b; i<=d; i+=b) { // i = i + b
 arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr.pop()); //Output is 98
*/
```

Comment: Looks like you've interchanged the variables `b` and `d`. Just swap the parameters in the function signature, and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It is working now.

Comment: I have added that as an answer too. May be you want to accept that as a valid answer. Answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577567/4391652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've interchanged the variables `b` and `d`. Just swap the parameters in the function signature, and you'll get what you expect.

The example you've shared will is working because you've used b as 7 and d as 100.
While in the actual code, the params you're passing are as follows:
b - 100, d - 7.
Therefore the `for` loop isn't executing even once, thereby logging `undefined` as mentioned by you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks mate! If I swap parameters it works how I need.

Comment: @MartyS Great to hear. Maybe you want to accept this as a valid answer if it is and helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with this line `for (let i = b; i <= d; i += b)`. In your program d is 7 and b is 100 so no element is ever pushed to array

```
function maxMultiple(d, b) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = b; i <= d; i += b) { // i = i + b
    arr.push(i)
  }
  if (d > 0 && b > 0) {
    return arr.pop(); // does not work - undefined
  } else {
    return d;
  }
}

console.log(maxMultiple(7, 100));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because 100 is less than 7. Array is empty. Nothing ever got pushed.

My guess is you got the two parameters in the wrong order.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

```js
function maxMultiple(d, b){
  const arr = []; 
  for (let i=b; i<=d; i+=b) { // i = i + b
       arr.push(i)
  }

  console.log(arr.length === 0); // array is empty here

  if (d>0 && b>0){
    let res; // cache result
    // pop() on empty array always gives undefined
    console.log([].pop() === (res = arr.pop()));
     return res; // does not work - undefined
  } else { 
    return d;
  }
 }

console.log(maxMultiple(7,100));  // Output is undefined
```

http://instacode.dev/#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

Comment: Thank you very much!